# cartodb.js without jqyery, backbone, mustache code merged?

Tags: carto

I found that cartodb.js has also the code of library like jquery, backbone, mustache etc. As on my project I am already adding jquery and I dont need backbone/mustache etc, so is there any cartodb.js without these libraries already included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get CartoDB.js without jQuery by using: http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb_nojquery.js